# the precision of printf with specifier "%g"

Tags: c, printf

Can anybody explain me how the `[.precision]` in printf works with specifier "%g"? I'm quite confused by the following output:

```
double value = 3122.55;
printf("%.16g\n", value); //output: 3122.55
printf("%.17g\n", value); //output: 3122.5500000000002
```

I've learned  that `%g` uses the shortest representation.

But the following outputs still confuse me

```
printf("%.16e\n", value); //output: 3.1225500000000002e+03
printf("%.16f\n", value); //output: 3122.5500000000001819
printf("%.17e\n", value); //output: 3.12255000000000018e+03
printf("%.17f\n", value); //output: 3122.55000000000018190
```

My question is: why `%.16g` gives the exact number while `%.17g` can't?

It seems 16 significant digits can be accurate. Could anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: It's never that way in IEEE floating-point numbers.

Comment: @user35443 It is in fact the IEEE float representation (ieee-754) that cause this.

Answer (score 20):

`%g` uses the shortest representation.

Floating-point numbers [usually aren't stored](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) as a number in base `10`, but `2` (performance, size, practicality reasons). However, whatever the base of your representation, there will always be rational numbers that will not be expressible in some arbitrary size limit for the variable to store them.

When you specify `%.16g`, you're saying that you want the shortest representation of the number given with a maximum of `16` significant digits.

If the shortest representation has more than `16` digits, `printf` will shorten the number string by cutting cut the `2` digit at the very end, leaving you with `3122.550000000000`, which is actually `3122.55` in the shortest form, explaining the result you obtained.

In general, `%g` will always give you the shortest result possible, meaning that if the sequence of digits representing your number can be shortened without any loss of precision, it will be done.

To further the example, when you use `%.17g` and the `17`th decimal place contains a value different from `0` (`2` in particular), you ended up with the full number `3122.5500000000002`.

> My question is: why `%.16g` gives the exact number while `%.17g`
> can't?

It's actually the `%.17g` which gives you the exact result, while `%.16g` gives you only a rounded approximate with an error (when compared to the value in memory).

If you want a more fixed precision, use `%f` or `%F` instead.

Comment: I know there is rouding errors when presenting a float. Which confused me is that it seems the first 16 significant digits is actually what I want with out rouding error. Why?

Comment: @cssmlulu The error is at the `17`th. `%.16g` says that you care only about the first `16` digits, and the last one is ignored. When having a lot of zeroes (not significant digits) at the end, `%g` cuts them off, making it just as short as `3122.55`.

Comment: @cssmlulu In addition to @user35443's comment, `%g` uses the number of significant digits as its precision specifier. It is more explained here: [What is the difference between %g and %f in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5913115/4895040). One of significant figures rule states that [ALL zeroes between non-zero numbers are ALWAYS significant.](http://www.usca.edu/chemistry/genchem/sigfig.htm), which will apply if you use `%.17g` on `3122.5500000000002` since zeroes between `5` and `2` are considered significant. That's why those zeroes are included.

Comment: It doesn't really undermine the main thrust of the argument here, but note that your claim that *"`%g` uses the shortest representation."* is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/54162152/1709587, where I rebut precisely that claim.

Comment: No, the `%.17g` does not give the exact representation. In fact, there is no way to store `3122.55` in a float exactly. The reality is that that number is stored as (`printf '%a\n' 3122.55`) `0x1.865199999999ap+11` which is mathematically exactly equal to `3122.550000000000181898940354585647583007812500`. However, it makes no sense to talk about "mathematically exact" of an approximation (rounded by ieee754).

Answer (score 8):

The decimal value 3122.55 can't be exactly represented in binary floating point. When you write

```
double value = 3122.55;
```

you end up with the closest possible value that can be exactly represented. As it happens, that value is *exactly* `3122.5500000000001818989403545856475830078125`.

That value to 16 significant figures is `3122.550000000000`. To 17 significant figures, it's `3122.5500000000002`. And so those are the representations that `%.16g` and `%.17g` give you.

Note that the nearest `double` representation of a decimal number is guaranteed to be accurate to at least 15 decimal significant figures. That's why you need to print to 16 or 17 digits to start seeing these apparent inaccuracies in your output in this case - to any smaller number of significant figures, the `double` representation is guaranteed to match the original decimal number that you typed.

One final note: you say that

> I've learned that `%g` uses the shortest representation.

While this is a popular summary of how `%g` behaves, it's also wrong. See [What precisely does the %g printf specifier mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54162152/1709587) where I discuss this at length, and show an example of `%g` using scientific notation even though it's 4 characters longer than not using scientific notation would've been.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal representation 3122.55 cannot be *exactly* represented by binary floating point representation.

A double precision binary floating point value can represent approximately 15 *significant figures* (note not *decimal places*) of a decimal value correctly; thereafter the digits may not be the same, and at the extremes do not even have any real meaning and will be an artefact of the conversion from the floating point representation to a string of decimal digits.

> I've learned that %g uses the shortest representation.

The rule is:

Where *P* is the precision (or 6 if no precision specified or 1 if precision is zero), and *X* is the decimal exponent required for E/e style notation then:

- if ***P* > *X* ≥ −4**, the conversion is with style f or F and precision ***P* − 1 − *X***.
- otherwise, the conversion is with style e or E and precision ***P* − 1**.

The modification of *precision* for `%g` results in the different output of:

```
printf("%.16g\n", value); //output: 3122.55
printf("%.16e\n", value); //output: 3.1225500000000002e+03
printf("%.16f\n", value); //output: 3122.5500000000001819
```

despite having the same precision in the format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

The exact representation in memory of the decimal 3122.55 is a binary fraction with a 53 bits mantissa.

```
printf("%a\n", value);     // output 0x1.865199999999ap+11
```

And the **exact** conversion back to a decimal is:

```
printf("%.45f\n", value);  // output 3122.550000000000181898940354585647583007812500000
```

If you cut that number at 17 digits you get:

```
printf("%.17g\n", value);  // output 3122.5500000000002
```

And at 16 digits, all the trailing digits are `0` and could safely be erased (which the `g` format does automatically by default) to get:

```
printf("%.16g\n", value);  // output 3122.55
```

That is why you get back the original decimal number.