# Float to int if the num has no numbers behind decimal point in C

Tags: c

how am I supposed to print a float so as if it has no numbers behind decimal point e.g. 11.00 should be printed as 11 but 11.45 should stay the same. The problem is some if statement maybe. Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try? And how many decimal places do you want printed. Suppose you have `1.124` or one seventh `0.14285714285714285714285714285714`?

Comment: `printf("%g\n", var);` where `var` is the name of your variable.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5913115/3436922)

Comment: BTW, if this is about currency, then you shouldn't store money in floats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf)

Comment: I think I have solved it by simply rounding the value and if rounded one is equal to original value, I will simply use %.0f formatting, else %.2f

Answer (score 2):

First solution that comes on my mind is cast.
This is what I would do.
Let's say your variable is "a", that you want to print.

```
    float a;

    if (if (a-(int)a<0.001 || (int)a-a<0.001) ) //1st comment explains this 
       printf("%d", (int)a);
    else
       printf("%f", a);
```

Comment: If a is 123.000001 this won't work. Always compare to some minimum, so: `if (a-(int)a<0.001 || (int)a-a<0.001) ...`

Comment: Thank you for advice, Paul. I totally forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printDouble(double fp);

int main(void)
{
    printDouble(11.0);
    printDouble(11.45);
}

void printDouble(double fp)
{
    double _fp;
    char buffer[40];
    int i = 0;
    do{
        sprintf(buffer, "%.*lf", i, fp);
        sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &_fp);
        i++;
    } while(fp != _fp);
    puts(buffer);
}
```

Output:

```
11
11.45
```

Perhaps this is somewhat inefficient, but it **does** work. Anyway, you don't need to print floating-point numbers frequently.

Comment: %e doesn't show an integer representation of a float, it uses scientific notation.

Therefore, with fp=100000.0, %g will show 1.0e+5, not 100000, which is what the OP is requesting.

Comment: The presence in the question of `if` statements is significative that the problem should be solved by hand, rather than through a function.

Comment: @DaveKnight Answer modified